# SpringBoot deserializing json instant to next day

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, jackson

So I observed how `@FutureOrPresent` was complaining for present date also. Debugging my code further

```
public class MyCustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Instant> {
    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    @Override
    public Instant deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(p.getText(), fmt);
        Instant instant = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant();
        return instant;
    }
}
```

Debugging gives me this state:

[image: state]

Any idea how this can be worked around? I'm in Asia/Kolkate zone if that helps

If I am passing current date in `fromDate` in the JSON file I'm getting this error:

`fromDate Must Be Of Future Or Present`

The POJO has this format

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyCustomDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @NotNull(message = "Please provide From Date")
    @FutureOrPresent(message = "From Date Must Be Of Future Or Present")
    private Instant fromDate;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does the value of the `Instant` not equal any (unknown) expected value? Could you please describe the problem more in detail? If you are in `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")`, then why do you use `ZoneId.of("UTC")` to create an `Instant` from a date only?

Comment: @deHaar For payload having `fromDate` as current date there is a false alarm on the present date. Even `27-10-2021` is getting caught by the validator despite being presnt date

Comment: an instant is an instant in time. if you do From the beginning of the day today that is in the past, which is not in the future or the present.

Comment: Indeed, you are checking date and time of day down to the smallest computable unit instead of just checking the date part you obviously get. `atStartOfDay()` will be before `Instant.now()` if you use today's date.

Comment: Use `LocalDate` instead of `Instant`, would be much more suitable if you want to compare dates (that consist of year, month of year and day of month).

Comment: @deHaar one constraint is the pojos have fields to be declared as instant hence I have to make this conversion

Comment: Which time zone is used by the API you are passing the `Instant` to? Are you sure you have to use `atStartOfDay()`? It's likely that the resulting `Instant` is before the other one taken for comparison.

Comment: @deHaar UTC is used by the API

Comment: you could try to use instead of at start of day
`LocalDateTime localDateTime= date.atTime(23, 59, 59);
localDateTime.atZone( ZoneId.of("UTC"));
localDateTime.toInstant();`

This will give you an instant that most likely will be of today but also always in the future or present most likely

Comment: @bgore This seems to be working, thanks. If you put it down below I can mark it answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem would be that you are using the time of the start of the day

if you use todays date that will always be in the past.
If you use today and want an instant that will be in the future you can get an instant at the end of the day instead

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime= date.atTime(23, 59, 59); 
localDateTime.atZone( ZoneId.of("UTC")); 
localDateTime.toInstant();
```

This will give you an instant that most likely will be of today but also always in the future or present most likely

You could also use an instant that is a minute in the future instead of at the end of the day.

An instant that is of the current time may fail as it takes time for the request to travel to the destination and its nice to have a little buffer